# Off-line mail reader?

Tags: email-client

I have an old email account on yahoo, that I don't use any more, but it contains a lot of important (to me) information. I have downloaded it all by going in to Thunderbird and synchronising it all, so now I have a directory like this:

```
# ll
total 1817808
-rw------- 2 root root   14864441 Mar 14 15:35 Archive
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root      59693 Mar 14 15:41 Archive.msf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       1395 Mar 14 15:37 Archives.msf
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root      50588 Mar 14 15:39 Bulk.msf
-rw------- 2 root root     315183 Mar 14 15:36 done
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root      46581 Mar 14 15:41 done.msf
-rw------- 2 root root    3539464 Mar 14 15:36 Draft
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root      88447 Mar 14 16:05 Draft.msf
-rw------- 1 root root    5777417 Mar 14 15:35 Drafts-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       5724 Mar 14 15:35 Drafts-1.msf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       2232 Mar 14 15:39 Drafts.msf
-rw------- 2 root root 1809561219 Mar 14 15:52 INBOX
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root    3176356 Mar 14 16:37 INBOX.msf
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root       2504 Mar 14 16:05 Junk.msf
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root         25 Mar 14 14:35 msgFilterRules.dat
-rw------- 1 root root   23355461 Mar 14 15:36 Sent-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     286525 Mar 14 15:36 Sent-1.msf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       1897 Mar 14 15:39 Sent.msf
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root      28190 Mar 14 16:05 Trash.msf
-rw------- 2 root root     202308 Mar 14 15:34 Unwanted
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root       4111 Mar 14 16:05 Unwanted.msf
```

I know I can read the emails in Thunderbird, but I want to get rid of the account on Yahoo, and it looks like Thunderbird insists on the account existing - at least if I don't want error messages when I am online with my new account.

So, what I'm looking for is something a bit like Thunderbird, but which only reads my local, off-line emails and doesn't require an existing, online account. They used to be common (yes, I'm that old) - but is there a modern version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Thunderbird, >Tools, >Account Settings, each email account will have a listing, specifically in this case, Server Settings. One can remove the check mark from ***check for new Messages at startup***, and from ***check for new messages every x minutes***.

This will allow you to continue to access the stored messages in Thunderbird without creating errors or accessing a dead account.